# Parameter Query is not working for API Get Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

If I am calling HttpGet method with Parameter Query , the Get method without parameter  is only called  . How can I call the second Get method  using parameter id=2

```
http://localhost:10436/api/testapi?id=2
```

Here is the code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace TestApi1
    {
        [Route("api/testapi")]
        [ApiController]
        public class TestApiController : ControllerBase
        {
            public ActionResult Get()
            {
                return Ok("Gets Working");
            }
    
            [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
            public ActionResult Get(int id)
            {
                return Ok("Gets Working with ID");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are defining the route in the httpGet. So this would actually be `/api/testapi/Id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All routes were tested using VS 2019 and Postman. They are working properly

if you want to use

```
http://localhost:10436/api/testapi?id=2
```

change your action

```
 public ActionResult GetById([FromQuery] int id)
{
   return Ok("Gets Working with ID");
}
```

but if you want to use action you already have , use this url

```
http://localhost:10436/api/testapi/2
```

Comment: Still not working . Is there any problem in launchsetting.json file.

Comment: @AlanPauil You have to post your startup file with endpoints config

Answer (score 0):

```
       [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Get (int id)
        {
           //clarify code
        }
```

And send this request `http://localhost:10436/api/testapi?id=2`.

Your code would work. your code does not work because of your id uppercase and the lowercase fact I think.

**UPDATE**

```
[HttpGet("idName/{id}")]
```

send this request `http://localhost:10436/api/testapi/idName?id=2`.

**ANOTHER PROCESS**

```
   [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
   public async Task<ActionResult> Get (int id)
        {
           //clarify code
        }
```

And send this request `http://localhost:10436/api/testapi?id=2`

**ANOTHER PROCESS AGAIN**

```
   [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetById")]
   public async Task<ActionResult> GetById (int id)
        {
           //clarify code
        }
```

And send this request `http://localhost:10436/api/testapi?id=2`

Comment: No still , the first Get Method is calling not calling the second method

Comment: @AlanPauil I updated my answer.please check.

Comment: @AlanPauil again i updated my answer by adding another process.it should work now.

Comment: @AlanPauil I Updated my answer again by changing your action name and it will my last try. it should work now. please check.